# Translate devise labels in registration?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, internationalization

I want to translate my labels in registration form, but I can't see what is the schema to follow in my .es locale. It wont work with "registrations". Someone knows? I can't find a correct answer in all the internet. Thanks

#### .es locale

```
  devise:
    registrations:
          name: "Nombre"
          email: "Email"
          password: "Contraseña"
          password_confirmation: "Recordarme"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's done via active record translations

```
es:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        password: "Contraseña"
        email: "Email"
        password_confirmation: "Recordarme"
```